# Why does comparing value with undefined returns false in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparison, undefined

I am new to Javascript and I noticed when a variable is `undefined`, comparing a number returns `false` as below. Why does comparing `undefined` with numbers return `false`?

```js
var a = undefined;
console.log(a < 10);
console.log(10 < a);
console.log(a == 10);
```

Comment: What would you expect those to return? Certainly not true

Comment: Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: Because you are comparing the global `undefined` property that represents the primitive value `undefined` against a `number` and that returns `false`.. More about [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how works in JavaScript.

```
Number(undefined) // NaN
NaN == NaN // false
NaN < 0 // false
NaN > 0 // false
```

So, while you compare it forces to check like:

```
Number(undefined) < 10
// undefined is coerced to check with number
```

And thus,

```
undefined == 10 // false
undefined > 10 // false
undefined < 10 // false
```